# SQLite limit is a string

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sql-limit

The [Android API docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) appear to suggest that the limit clause to provide when querying a SQLite database is a string.
This does not make much sense to me.
Presumably, it is converted internally to an integer?
Or are there other issues involved here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they key thing to consider is that the parameter isn't solely for the single 1st part (see expr1 below) but for the entire `LIMIT` **Clause**.

This clause can be as as simple as just a single integer, but it can also be relatively complex; the full syntax of a `LIMIT` Clause is :-

`LIMIT expr1 OFFSET (or ,) expr2;` [see - SELECT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

Where :-

- **expr1** should resolve to an integer specifying the maximum number of rows to be returned and
- **expr2** is an integer that specifies the offset (where 1 is the 1st) from the start of the potential rows to be returned.
- either expression could, at least in theory, be a subquery e.g.

  - `String limit_clause = "(SELECT numbertoshow FROM types WHERE id =  (random() & 1)+1)";`
  - P.S. not saying this is a useful example rather it is an example that works and is for illustration of a complex LIMIT clause and as such an example of why a String as opposed to an Integer is the more flexible/useful parameter type.

---

---

The complete SQL used for testing the above was :-

```
/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS basetable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS basetable (basename TEXT);
INSERT INTO basetable VALUES('test001');
INSERT INTO basetable VALUES('test002');
INSERT INTO basetable VALUES('test003');
INSERT INTO basetable VALUES('test004');
INSERT INTO basetable VALUES('test005');
INSERT INTO basetable VALUES('test006');
INSERT INTO basetable VALUES('test007');
INSERT INTO basetable VALUES('test008');
INSERT INTO basetable VALUES('test009');
INSERT INTO basetable VALUES('test010');
INSERT INTO basetable VALUES('test011');
INSERT INTO basetable VALUES('test012');
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS types;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS types (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, typename TEXT, numbertoshow INTEGER);
INSERT INTO types VALUES(null,'type001',3);
INSERT INTO types VALUES(null,'type002',4);
*/
SELECT * FROM basetable LIMIT (SELECT numbertoshow FROM types WHERE id =  (random() & 1)+1);
```

- Note commented out statements are commented out as they are just needed the once.